# PHP session variable to be added to URL (and Vice Versa)

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, url

When users enter my site for the first time they are asked to select a location, this determines their currency. When selected, the country code is stored in `$_SESSION['countryCode']`and displayed onscreen.

However I'd also like to have this reflect in the URL, for instance if the user selected Germany the url would redirect to `http://test.com/de/`. Additionally I'd also like it if the user typed the above URL then when the page loads for it to set the session as `'de'`.

I'm not sure where to start with this I presume we'd have to do a url rewrite within the htaccess file but I don't know how this would interact with the php session, so any help would be thoroughly appreciated.

All the best,
Matt

Comment: You need to show your codes, or others won't know how to help you. Basically, you need a base controller to handle the language, the routing function will direct the user to the base controller , the controller read the country code in url to set the session.

Comment: Get the uri with `$_SERVER['request_uri']` then get the de part from the string and save it in session.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to store your country session globally and then reference it in your header/bootstrap file.

I would personally run a switch statement to determine how URLs are structured with a default to GB.

```
session_start();

// Assuming your country has come in from a validated form post.
$urlBit = $_POST['country'];

switch($urlBit) {
    case 'de':
        $country = $urlBit;
        break;
    case 'es':
        $country = $urlBit;
        break;
    default:
        $country = 'gb';
        break;
}

$_SESSION['country'] = $country;
```

Regarding the vice-versa, you could write some code to put the URL into a string and look for '/de/', '/gb/' within the string.

Again, I would revert back to a switch statement to handle that and once you know your result. Then, store it all using `$_SESSION['country']`.

```
session_start();

// Assumed URL structure. 
$url = 'http://www.website.com/de/';

// The switcheroo.
$urlParts = explode('/', $url);
$urlBit   = $urlParts[3]; // Returns 'de'

// The same switch as above. Stick it in a function or class/method, maybe.
switch($urlBit) {
    case 'de':
        $country = $urlBit;
        break;
    case 'es':
        $country = $urlBit;
        break;
    default:
        $country = 'gb';
        break;
}

$_SESSION['country'] = $country;
```

This is the best answer I can offer without seeing code first, but this simple logic would solve your issue, assuming you knew how to implement the above.

You could easily do this without htaccess but it's hard to say without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

initially at a login then cuntry is located by gps. then depending on the cuntry u write the php code like as.initially u defind the cuntry currency values..

use `case` or `if condition`

for select currency cuntry 
like as

```
 switch($cuntry_name)

{case(germany):

 $_SESSION['countryCode'] = 'de';
 break;
case(...):
$_SESSION['countryCode'] = '..';
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without .htaccess.
Create a lang file that you include in all your script. That lang file will have a variable generated from your session variable that will be appended to all your links and it will have the carrying the currency code